# ASP.NET MAUI Request.QueryString

Tags: asp.net, maui

I am building a asp.net maui app that uses a webview. I am trying to capture the Request object when the user navigates in the website.

My first question is if this is even possible?

I have tried nearly every single solution I have found.
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }
}
```

in my profile page where I need to request the querystring

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public Profile(ProfileViewModel vm, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
    InitializeComponent();
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    BindingContext = vm;
}

private void GetQueryString() {
    var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    var queryString = context.Request.QueryString.ToString();
}
```

this throws the following error:
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor'

Profile.xaml page
<ContentPage
...


<WebView.Behaviors>
<local:OpenInBrowser PropertyChanging="OpenInBrowser_PropertyChanging" />
</WebView.Behaviors>

I also tried this OpenInBrowser_PropertyChanging handler
the only method that fires is the OnAttached
this method fires only once when the app launches

```
public class OpenInBrowser : Behavior<WebView>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(WebView webview) {
        base.OnAttachedTo(webview);
        webview.Navigating += OnNavigating;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(WebView webview) {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(webview);
        webview.Navigating -= OnNavigating;
    }

    private void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e) {
        if(e.Url.StartsWith("http")) {
            //Device.OpenUri(new Uri(e.Url));
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.It is not recommended to [use IHttpContextAccessor/HttpContext in Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor).

2.Generally, Query parameter in Blazor can use GetUriWithQueryParameter of NavigationManager, specifically, you can refer to [URI and navigation state helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you supported, you should know that [it is not recommended to use IHttpContextAccessor/HttpContext in Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor).

If you want to query parameters in Blazor,you can use
`Navigation.GetUriWithQueryParameter("{NAME}", {VALUE})` of [NavigationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers), The `{NAME}` placeholder specifies the query parameter name, the `{VALUE}` placeholder specifies the value as a supported type.

For more details, you can refer to [Query String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers).